# GNU Screen: files to numbered buffers?

Tags: buffer, gnu-screen

I unefficiently use "^a + ESC SPACE -- SPACE" and "^a + ]".

**1. How can I copy a big file to GNU Screen buffer like**

```
^a + : cat big_file > new_buffer

^a + : new_buffer ]
```

**2. How can specify the number for each buffer like**

```
^a + : cat big_file 2> new_buffer_number_2

^a + 2]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you actually want to *do*, rather than making up syntax that doesn't work and making us guess what it might do. Also, this question isn't programming related and probably belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: If the data is in a file, why would you want it in the screen buffer?  Once in the buffer, presumably you will want to use it elsewhere (say, to do foo), so perhaps your question should be "how do I use data in a file to do foo?"

Comment: Pursell: The power is not in the command itself, but in its use with other small apps. For example, I can paste a file to pastebin.com, by copying/pasting to/from the buffer. I can fast send an email in Mutt. I can reuse my functions in BC. I hope you see the property is a Killer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want `:readbuf`?

```
^A :readbuf /path/to/file
^A ]
```

I haven't used 'buffers' in GNU Screen (never knew they existed), but I'm guessing `:readreg` is the buffer-y version of `:readbuf`:

```
^A :readreg x /path/to/file
^A :paste x
```

Comment: `CTRL-A :readreg a /path/to/file` followed by `CTRL-A :paste a` to paste

Comment: (buffer names are one character)

Comment: rampion: strager:  Very cool! I knew Screen had the property :D Just awesome, I will use it over Mutt, ELinks, BC and many other apps. Great thanks!