# GNU Screen: programmer-quotes ` ` in Readbuf?

Tags: gnu-screen, quoting

The [commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318046/gnu-screen-files-to-numbered-buffers/1318064#1318064) need absolute paths in slurping. So I need programmer-quotes, because of laziness to write long paths. How can I use them like:

```
^a :readbuf `pwd`/file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to assume that it is possible to use backticks in this way. However, `screen` does not appear to support backticks in the `:readbuf` command. It also does not support other shell conventions such as `~` for home directory, or `$XYZ` for environment variable expansions.

When `screen` reads the file named in the `:readbuf` command, the file name is relative to the current directory where `screen` started, not the current directory of whatever is displayed in the active window. This might be why you found that absolute paths worked for you. Try using a filename relative to whatever directory you started `screen` from originally.

**Update**: For additional work on this answer, see: [GNU Screen: Environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318210/gnu-screen-environment-variables/1318301#1318301)

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. -Yes, I do not use enough "^a + d" and "screen -r PID". Have to change it :D