# GNU Screen: Environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, buffer, gnu-screen

***[Updated]***
The question is related to the questions [GNU Screen: Programmers quotes in Readbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318186/gnu-screen-programmer-quotes-in-readbuf) and [GNU Screen: files to numbered buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318046/gnu-screen-files-to-numbered-buffers). Since they are not solved, the question targets more general concept about environment variables. My belief is that they are the key to make Screen more efficient.

**1. How can I use Bash's variables in Screen like:**

```
$ export path=`pwd`
$ ^a :readbuf `echo $path`/debugging_code.php
```

**2. How can I reuse Screen's buffers like:**

```
$ ^a :readreg a `echo $path`
$ ^a :readbuf $a/debugging_code.php
$ ^a ]
```

**3. How can I use Screen's buffers like environment variables?**

Comment: This appears to be the same question as the one I just answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318186/gnu-screen-programmer-quotes-in-readbuf

Comment: Greg: Updated, hopefully more clear now.

Comment: counter-question for (1): when you have multiple shells open, each with a different environment, which shell's environment variables do you want screen to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command does not create a new screen session, but it will create a screen internal variable. Running it on the command line allow you to use the shell expansion:

```
$ screen -X setenv a "$PWD/debugging_code.php"
```

Then use the new variable:

```
C-a :readbuf $a
```

Comment: +1 for its coolness. A similar in Ubuntu 'screen -X export foo="foo world"' did not work for some reason.

Comment: Note that the setenv in this context is a screen command not a *shudder* csh command.

Comment: Would you clarify how you use it. Dunno why it does not work on my Ubuntu.

Comment: Masi, reading your first comment, I suspect you figured that the "setenv" above is a csh construct, and you replaced it with the equivalent bash "export" constant. However "setenv" here is a GNU screen command. For more information grep "-X" in `screen --help; also grep "setenv" in man screen.

Comment: This is the best possible solution IMHO, since tapping into the current window's shell for environmental variables seems insecure, difficult (how many hops of ssh have you gone through?), and not necessarily optimal (maybe I don't want my screen's environment variables to change every time I change windows).  This leaves the shell's work to the shell, and lets screen do what it needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a patch to screen 4.0.3 that supports the following syntax:

```
^A :readbuf !shell-command
```

This allows you to exec any arbitrary shell command and pipe the output into the screen buffer. Note that this is implemented by executing a subshell using `popen` and copying the standard output to the current file specified in the `bufferfile` setting (and then reading that file), so be careful you don't overwrite something you don't intend to. Also, this patch is probably terribly insecure so please use it at your own risk.

An example might be:

```
^A :readbuf !cat $HOME/projects/foobar/file.txt
```

Any shell command is executed literally as typed.

See [gnu-screen-readbuf-exec](http://github.com/ghewgill/gnu-screen-readbuf-exec) on Github for the Git repository containing the patch.